# Router.navigate doesnt work, url changes but site doesnt reload

Tags: angular, typescript, navigation

I'm creating an Angular 12 application but i'm facing a few issues. One of them is that my sidenavigation isn't working. The flow goes to that the site URL is changed but the site doesn't reload? Can you see why?

Angular version 12.1.2; Node version 16.13.2; npm 8.1.2

Sidenav.html

```
<div class="side-navbar">
  <div class="nav-row" (click)="Nav('home')">
    <div class="logo-placeholder">
      <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
    </div>
    <div class="text-placeholder">
      <span>Home</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

ts file

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-side-nav',
  templateUrl: './side-nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./side-nav.component.scss']
})

export class SideNavComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router) {}


  ngOnInit(): void {}

  public Nav(link) {
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
  }
}
```

url goes to localhost:4200 but the site doesnt reload.

Comment: Did you include ```<router-outlet></router-outlet>```?

Comment: yes, but this is inside the the material sidenavigation content. Does this matter? And if so, What would an ideal structure be then?

Comment: we have components inside the router-outlet that also use routerlink but they also dont work